# c++ large numbers in factorial

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program with the problem "Given a positive integer **a**, what is the minimum positive integer **g** such that **g!** is a multiple of the square of **a!**?

Sample Input

1 (test case)

4

Sample Output

8

Explanation:  8!=40320 is divisible by 4!^2=24^2=576. Furthermore, it is the smallest one because  7!=5040 is not divisible by 576.

The program is successful, but i'm having trouble when the input is larger than about 20. It wont output anything.

Any suggestions?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
long long a,b,c=1,d,e=1,f=1,g=0,k;
cin>>a;
while(a>0){
    cin>>b;
    g=0;
    e=1;
    c=1;
    f=1;
    for (long long i=1; i<=b; i++){
        c=c*i;
    }
    d=c*c;
    for(long long j=1; e!=0; j++){
        f=f*j;
        g=g+2;
        e=f%d;
        if(c==e)
        cout<<g<<endl;
    }
    a--;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: 21! is greater than 2^63 (long long) which gives you integer overflow problem. You will have to either devise a method to strip trailing zeros from factorials or write a custom big integer class

Comment: *Any suggestions* -- Yes -- Use [boost](http://ideone.com/Y8A8Is).  Same code (except for the output of the actual factorial and the usage of `cpp_int`).

Answer (score 0):

Brute force will lead to integer overflow for all inputs whose value is more than 20. I got a better solution of this problem whose time complexity is `O(T)` where `T = number of test cases` and it uses constant space.

Solution  :   **Value of `g` will be equal to `2*a`for all a**.

```
         (a!)^2 = (a!)*a*(a-1)*(a-2)*..3*2*1
```

Our aim is to make `(a!)*a*(a-1)*(a-2)*..3*2*1` in the form of `g!` by multiplying with minimum possible integer required to do so.

If we multiply `2` with each of `a,a-1,a-2,...,3,2,1`, then we will get

```
        (a!)*2a*(2a-2)*(2a-4)*..6*4*2
```

This is too close to become factorial of an integer. Now it's trivial to make it equal to `2*a!`.

*Till now we got a number which is divisible by `(a^2)!` but we don't know whether this will be minumum such integer or not.*

This `2a` will be minimum such number as you have twice `1s,2s,3s,4s,...,ns` in `(a^2)!` and all these should be present in `g!` as  `(a^2)!` divides `g!`. This argument proves that `2*a` is the minimum such integer.

Comment: With a=6, g=10 works.  `2a`  is the _maximum_ value to consider for `g`,  In select cases, `g` may be less.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions?

Avoid wide math.

---

It certainly appears `g >= a`, so ....

`a!` is a factor of `g!` and `a!` is a factor of `square(a!)`, so we can simplify the problem.  Divide both side by `a!`

```
g!/a! = 1 *  a+1 * a+2 * ... * g
square(a!)/a! = a!
```

Now find smallest `g` such that `(a+1 * a+2 * ... * g) % a! == 0`

Each of these `a+1, a+2,  ..., g` terms may have factors in `a!`.  A solution *must* be found by the time `g` reaches `2a`, but maybe sooner.  As each term is found, factor it out of `a!` and test for mod-ness  This keeps the need for wide integer to a minimum.

---

Something like the following.  Unfortunately I can not test it out right now.  IAC, OP was looking for suggestions, not code.

```
unsigned SOPP_LargeFactor(unsigned a) {
  unsigned i = 1;
  unsigned long long prod = 1;
  for (unsigned g=a+1; ; g++) {
    prod *= g;
    while (prod%i == 0) {
      if (i == a) return g;
      prod /= i;
      i++; 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

g!= k·a!<sup>2</sup>. After some descomposition, k=(a+1)(a+2)...g / (2*3*4...a)

If k is integer this means that it's possible to find divisions with also an integer result. More, ALL divisions must be integer.

First, decompose numerator and denominator into prime factors. I.e. 7! = 7·6·5·4·3·2= 7·5·3<sup>2</sup>·2<sup>4</sup>

Then, if g is a solution, ALL denominator factors *must be found also in the numerator* (e.g. 3<sup>5</sup> in numerator includes 3<sup>2</sup> in denominator), and thus can be cancelled. Multiplying the remaining factors in numerator just give us k, which is not needed.

You can set a loop to test several g until this condition is met. I'd store primes and their exponent so cancelling is a matter of decreasing exponents.

Last, no *Big Number* calculations are involved. g is only limited by sizeof(long).